# Don't know if pump is hers or not

Tags: pump, well-pump, well

It's -15 outside and windy. My pump light was on and no water in my water tank. I am not sure how long the light was on, so I think the line from my trailer into the ground froze. What what happened to the pump? It was calling for water. The points are on. It is a submersible.

Comment: "pump is hers" ? Sounds like an autocorrect error but not sure what you are trying to say. Also not sure about "the points are on".

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you with this.

Comment: how are we supposed to know what the light indicates?

Answer (score 2):

With -15 temp the line in the ground is probably frozen. When you used some water the pressure tank pressure dropped turning on the pump. I would turn the breaker off until the line thaws or your pump will continue to run. With the pump dead headed it can damage the pump if left on and your power bill will go up.